# Access to the user's reels media feed highlight story (Get all user's stories) by `mgp25/Instagram-API` project

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I use [`mgp25/Instagram-API`](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API) release `^5.0` stable version.

I need to get all medias of the user's story.

I have this code:

```
$user = 'instagram';
$userId = $ig->people->getUserIdForName($user);
$feedId = $ig->highlight->getUserFeed($userId)->getTray()[0]->getId();
var_dump( $ig->story->getReelsMediaFeed($feedId)->getReels() );
```

Result (data is in the `_objectData` private method):

```
object(InstagramAPI\Response\Model\UnpredictableKeys\ReelUnpredictableContainer)#1453 (4) {
  ["_type":protected]=>
  string(33) "\InstagramAPI\Response\Model\Reel"
  ["_cache":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_compiledPropertyMapLink":"LazyJsonMapper\LazyJsonMapper":private]=>
  &array(0) {
  }
  ["_objectData":"LazyJsonMapper\LazyJsonMapper":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["highlight:17907400474216512"]=>
    array(13) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(27) "highlight:17907400474216512"
      ["latest_reel_media"]=>
      int(1520611200)
      ["seen"]=>
      NULL
:
:
```

I try this code:

```
var_dump( $ig->story->getReelsMediaFeed($feedId)->getReels()[$feedId] );
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type InstagramAPI\Response\Model\UnpredictableKeys\ReelUnpredictableContainer as array in...
```

And also I try this code:

```
var_dump( $ig->highlight->getUserFeed($userId)->getTray()[0]->getItems() );
```

But return `NULL`.

I can use `jsonSerialize()` or same methods:

```
var_dump( $ig->story->getReelsMediaFeed($feedId)->getReels()->jsonSerialize()->$feedId );
```

But I don't like it, and this is a funny way that will disappear as the class and form of the structure also disappear.

What's your standard solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the source code, you want to use the `getData()` method of [`InstagramAPI\Response\Model\UnpredictableKeys\ReelUnpredictableContainer`](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/src/Response/Model/UnpredictableKeys/ReelUnpredictableContainer.php)

```
$reels = $ig->story->getReelsMediaFeed($feedId)->getReels()->getData();
```

The `getData()` method (from `CoreUnpredictableContainer`) converts the data into an instance of the `$_type` property.

`$reels` is now an instance of [`InstagramAPI\Response\Model\Reel`](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/src/Response/Model/Reel.php). It's unclear what data you want from that but the API is defined pretty well in the class itself, eg

```
$items = $reels->getItems();
$location = $reels->getLocation();
// etc
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `reels` is an array, so it's works: `$ig->story->getReelsMediaFeed($feedId)->getReels()->getData()[$feedId]->getItems()`